# Dart. Where argument of anonymous function came from?

Tags: dart, anonymous-function, lexical-closures

In example below there `(num i)` stuff, where it get it's value when `makeAddr()` called ?

```
Function makeAdder(num addBy) {
  return (num i) => addBy + i;
}

void main() {
  // Create a function that adds 2.
  var add2 = makeAdder(2);

  // Create a function that adds 4.
  var add4 = makeAdder(4);

  assert(add2(3) == 5);
  assert(add4(3) == 7);
}
```

Comment: @Jay but 3 should go into `addBy`, how it's got into `i` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `makeAdder` function returns function. The function it returns is created by evaluating the function expression `(num i) => addBy + i`.
When you evaluate a function *expression* you create a function *value*. The function value is also called a *closure* because it contains ("closes over") all the "free" variables in the function body - those that are not declared by the function expression itself

In this case the function expression `(num i) => addBy + i` contains the free variable `addBy`. The function value/closure knows what that variable means - it's the parameter of the call to `makeAdder` that the function expression is evaluated in. Every call to `makeAdder` creates a new `addBy` variable, and every call also creates a new closure closing over that new variable.

The closure is not just storing the value of the variable, it's referencing the *variable* itself. You can see that if your closure changes the value of variable.

Example:

```
/// Creates a counter function which returns a new value each call.
///
/// The counter function starts at [start] and increments by [step]
/// each time it is called.
int Function() makeCounter([int start = 1, int step = 1]) {
  var value = start - step;
  return () => value += step;
}

main() {
  var countFrom1 = makeCounter();
  var countFast = makeCounter(1, 2);
  var countFrom100 = makeCounter(100);

  // Prints 1, 2, 3, 4, 5:
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) print(countFrom1()); 

  // Prints 1, 3, 5, 7, 9:
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) print(countFast()); 

  // Prints 100, 101, 102, 103, 104:
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) print(countFrom100()); 

  print(countFrom1());  // Prints 6.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a closure. When makeAdder returns, it's returning a function that already has addBy in scope, and that scope is frozen.